# Animated pendulum effect

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create an animated pendulum. I managed to do it with two nested div, one for the string and one for the pendulum. The animation is done by rotating the string from 45 deg like so :

```
.string{
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
  50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

It works fine, but the impression of speed is not great.

Now I would like that pendulum's speed decreases from `0deg` to `45deg` and increases when going from `45deg` to `0deg`.

**How could I achieve this ?**

Comment: BTW, a pendulum's swing follows the sine function. You may want to use that as a custom easing function instead of the built-in `ease-in-out`. Choose `easeInOutSine` from the [Caseer](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/) web app or [easings.net](http://easings.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice tool for building custom easing effects: [**Ceaser**](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)

But, because you're using the same animation to do the back and forth, i think you can handle it with:

```
.string{
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; /* or make your custom easing */
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  40%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
  70%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}​
```

So that it takes 40% of the time to go up, and only 30% to go down :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is below:

```
.string{
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); }
}
```

This will create a smooth animation going from 45 degrees on either sides. You can increase or decrease the frequency using the animation duration.

Answer (score 1):

I found by this resource by Googling [CSS3 Pendulum](http://daneden.me/2011/04/pendulum-effect-in-css/). It seems to be what you are looking for.

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iKICp) using your code:

```
.string{
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is `-webkit-animation-timing-function`. Try playing around with the different values to see how it effects the speed of the animation.

See: http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp

Also wouldn't it make more sense to set the direction to alternate and then animate a single swing? That way it would play left to right then right to left. Using the default timing-function of 'ease' you would get what would appear to be correct physics for a swinging pendulum motion.

Comment: a lot of people don't like w3schools as a reference because some of its content is outdated and incorrect - I see a lot of downvotes on answers that reference it.

Comment: I agree with you it is a load of crap, but in this instance it seemed an easy point out. Have you got a personal preference for a w3schools alternate? I don't seem to use one set place but it would be nice to know the favorites...

Comment: The w3c just launched a new doc site but failing that the best references are a combination of mozilla, apple and msft documentation and then there's always the W3C specs - which are actually pretty readable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have created a version of pendulum effect myself.
http://codepen.io/khanhhua/full/jbOLJb/

Technically, the implementation would involve transform, transform-origin, animation-timing-function and several more calculations. I did the following code in SCSS (you can see in [the pen above](http://codepen.io/khanhhua/full/jbOLJb/)).

For more details, you can read [in my blog](http://fatmandesigner.com/pendulum-effect/) which shows you more on the math and physics behind.

Hope this would help!

```
[class*=pendulum] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 112px;
  border: 2px solid #white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #5c9bf3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px white;
  animation: swing 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
[class*=pendulum]:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  background: white;
  animation: tracing 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}

.pendulum-1 {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform-origin: center -512px;
  transform-origin: center -512px;
  animation-duration: 1.13542s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.pendulum-1:after {
  height: 512px;
  margin-top: -512px;
  animation-timing-function: step(0, 4);
  animation-delay: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 0.56771s;
}
```

PS: If you are looking for the answer for some interview question, be sure that you mention the source. You may never know that I am the interviewer.